# Edit Mode Transform Median X, Y, Z location. How to read the N-Panel

Tags: python

Rather than recalculate it - How can I read the Transform Median X,Y,Z that is displayed in the Transform Median Dialog.[image: Screen Shot of Transform Median].

The code to calculate it is straight forward but I'm just curious as to "where this data is coming from"?.    It's right there and I can't get my pythonic hands on it.

The tool help for it is bpy.ops.ui.editsource but the documentation doesn't reveal anything.

Should I be looking in the BMesh class?

Similarly:   In object mode - the Transform Location is that of the last selected object.
But the "pop up tool tip" at least gives me the "Slot Info"

[image: Popup reveals the slots for bpy.data.objects["Cube"].location 0, 1, and 2.]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a response but this is the code that I used:
I think the original author was CodeManX

```
    def calcpivotpoint(theobject):
        ob = theobject
        me = ob.data    

        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
        verts_sel = [v.co for v in bm.verts if v.select]

        pivot = sum(verts_sel, Vector()) / len(verts_sel)

        return ob.matrix_world @ pivot
```